# Suprema and infima in real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I am having troubles when finding suprema and infima of sets. Could the supremum exist when the set is bounded from above?

For example, $A=\{x\in \Bbb R \mid x^2<5\}$, the supremum is $\sqrt5$, the infimum is $-\sqrt5$ (is it right?).

But for $B=\{x\in \Bbb Q \mid x^2<5\}$, what are the supremum and infimum?

For $C=\{x\in \Bbb Z \mid x^2<5\}$, the supremum is $2$, the infimum is $-2$, and for $D=\{x\in \Bbb N \mid x^2<5\}$, the supremum is $2$, the infimum is 1. Are my answers correct for set $C$ and set $D$? (Note: $\Bbb N$ represents natural numbers and $0$ is not included.)

Moreover, what if we have a set $S=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty ({-1\over n},{1\over n}]$ ? What are the supremum and infimum? The set is getting narrower as n goes to infinity, and I think $0$ could be neither supremum nor infimum.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ah thank you that was a silly mistake.

Comment: Don't forget that squaring real numbers will make them nonnegative, so $-\infty$ is not an infimum for any of the above.

Comment: @Clayton I see. Correct them already. Thank you!

Comment: For $D$, depends on your definition of $\mathbb N$. Sone people define it to include zero, some people do not.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews well in real analysis(what I am learning), 0 is not included.

Comment: I promise you, in some real analysis classes, it does include zero. :) @MaggieMak

Answer (score 2):

For A, C, and D your answers are right (modulo Thomas Andrew's comment about $\Bbb{N}$.

Set $B$ has no $\sup x$ or $\inf x$.  That not-quite-trivial fact leads into the whole business of Dedekind cuts and putting the definition of the real line onto a rigorous footing.

Finally, since every $S_n =({-1\over n},{1\over n}]$ contains $0$, and for no other $x \in \Bbb{R}$ can we make that statement, $S = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty S_n$ has zero as its supremum and its infinum.

Comment: But the supremum and infimum need not to be in the set, right? For B, why $\sqrt5$ and $-\sqrt5$ cannot be the supremum and infimum?

Comment: If you consider $\Bbb{Q}$ as a subset of $\Bbb{R}$ then $\sqrt{5}$ is indeed the supremum.  If you consider only $\Bbb{Q}$ as the universe, then there is no supremum. I suspect the former viewpoint is more common, but given this was posed as a (homework?) problem, I suspect the poser was looking for the fact that within $\Bbb{Q}$ alone the sup does not exist.